# Can contract create and control a proxy account?

Tags: ink, smart-contract, account

Can a smart contract create and control a proxy account?
If yes, how can I create a proxy account for a contract and how can I send transactions from my contract on behalf of my contract's proxy account?

Answer (score 1):

No, smart contracts don't have keys and can't sign messages. They have an account id, but they're not able to act as a signed origin. AFAIK the only easy way you can do that is through a pallet, such as the [proxy pallet](https://docs.rs/pallet-proxy/latest/pallet_proxy/).